# Why do automated Hasura migrations output a metadata.yaml file?

Tags: hasura

I am [using the console](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/migrations/new-database.html#step-3-open-the-console-from-the-cli) to generate migrations. In addition to the generated migrations, Hasura also writes a `metadata.yaml` file next to the migration folders:

```
- config.yaml
- migrations/
    |-- 1583186121964_init/
    |-- 1583363878794_another_migration/
    |-- metadata.yaml  <-- This file is generated along with new migrations,
                           but seems redundant
```

This seems to be the latest version of the metadata. However, this file does not seem necessary. I can wipe my Hasura state—both PostgresSQL and Hasura—remove this file, and upon `hasura migrate apply` everything is correctly restored based on the migrations alone. What is this file for? Just in case the migrations are bad?

Comment: What version of Hasura? And what is inside metadata.yaml exactly? I have not seen that before - all metadata changes are managed through migrations to my understanding so I agree you should be able to correctly restore based on migrations alone.

Comment: Thanks for your perspective. I believe it's because I am using v1.2.0 (beta) of the client. Inside the file is a full metadata dump, like you would get from the console or CLI. I believe it's 1.2.0-related and will be explained as those docs are updated (https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/4050)

Comment: I can see this file generated with version 1.1.1